# html center align not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align the ul to the center of the div, it's not working here is my HTML code is:

```
<div id="container">  
  <div id="footer">  
    <ul id="footer_links">  
      <li><a href="...">About</a></li>  
      <li><a href="...">Faq</a></li>  
      <li><a href="...">How Rang De Works</a></li>  
      <li><a href="...">Contact</a></li>  
      <li><a href="...">Support</a></li>  
    </ul>  
  </div>  
<div>
```

My CSS is:

```
#container {width:975px;margin:0 auto;}  
#footer {text-align:center;}  
ul#footer_links {margin:0px;text-align:center;}  
ul#footer_links li {float:left; list-style:none; padding:10px 0px 0px 20px;}
```

Link to [HTML code](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/bQ28B/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `float: left` from `ul#footer_links li` and use `display: inline` instead

**JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Efbjv/1/**

Comment: No problem - adding a float will remove any centering effects that you have added

Answer (score 2):

`text-align:center;` is just to align pure text inside an element. If you want to center a block elements, you should use `margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;` in the element that will be centered.

Comment: Or maybe define elements as `display: inline-block;`

Comment: this will only work if footer has fixed width, which isn't the case... and text-align is not just for text, it's for all inline elements - see solution of my head hurts

Answer (score 0):

```
#footer{
    text-align:center;
}
ul#footer_links{
   margin:0px auto;
   width:90%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#container{width:975px;margin:0 auto; border:1 px solid #000;}
#footer{text-align:center;}
ul#footer_links{margin:0 auto; text-align:center;}
ul#footer_links li{ list-style:none;  display:inline; padding:10px 0px 0px 20px;}
```

Should solve the problem, changed ul#footer-links to be centered instead and the li element is now inline so it doesn't make a linebreak after each li.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS property `text-align` only affects inline elements, not block elements. So you have to make your `ul` and `li` elements inline, like:

```
#container{ width:975px; margin:0 auto; }
#footer{ text-align:center; }
ul#footer_links{ margin:0px;text-align:center; display:inline; }
ul#footer_links li{ display:inline; list-style:none; padding:10px 0px 0px 20px; }
```